# How to estimate a weekly script for feed BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've been running the `pypinfo` command in my terminal to get some data about Python packages. It is useful to get the most downloaded packages from PyPi. Here's the command I used:
`pypinfo --days 5 --limit 5 "" project`
And here's the output:

```
Served from cache: False
Data processed: 96.68 GiB
Data billed: 96.68 GiB
Estimated cost: $0.48
| project | download_count |
| -------- | -------------- |
| boto3 | 110,257,292 |
| awscli | 75,639,615 |
| botocore | 63,615,409 |
| urllib3 | 51,816,418 |
| requests | 42,656,848 |
| Total | 343,985,582 |
```

I'm trying to calculate how much I am going to spend if I feed my BigQuery database table with the most popular packages from PyPi weekly. My goal is to store the 5000 most downloaded package names and download count. However, I'm not sure if is common to spend 70+ USD per week.
Does anyone know if is it the default for weekly feeds?
Thanks in advance for your help!

The Pypinfo is from: https://github.com/ofek/pypinfo

Comment: Don't waste your time and money, the dataset already exist! Go there and explore it: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/gcp-public-data-pypi/pypi